# how to display an image to gridview using image path from stored procedure in a class library

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio

I want to store an image from a database to a gridview using a class library stored procedure. The image path is stored in the database is `~/App_LocalResources/Profile_BrgyCitizen/image.png`

My database table is named "TblBrgyCitizen" and the `name | data type` for the image is `ProfilePic | nvarchar(MAX)`

Filename of stored procedure => GridviewBrgyCitizen

Stored Procedure SQL to display into gridview is

`SELECT ProfilePic, FullName`

Class Library code (see below)

```
public DataSet GridviewBrgyCitizen()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GridviewBrgyCitizen", myConn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            
            return ds;
        }
```

aspx file code for gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="5" ForeColor="#333333"
                        CssClass="grid-view-style" AllowPaging="True" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Height="20px" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ProfilePic" HeaderText="Profile Pic" >
                                <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
                                <ItemStyle Height="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />
                            </asp:ImageField>
```

aspx.cs file for where the gridview resides

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                GETGridviewBrgyCitizen();
        }

        DataAccess myData = new DataAccess();

        public void GETGridviewBrgyCitizen()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = myData.GridviewBrgyCitizen();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

```
<table class="brgy-citizen-table-style">
            <tr>
                <td class="td-topleft-header">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearchBox" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearchBox" class="search-box" Placeholder="Name keywords" /><input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch" value="Search" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch" class="search-button-style" /></td>
                <td class="td-topright-header">
                    <button id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdd" class="add-button-style"><span>ADD</span></button>
                    <button id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnView" style="display: none;"><span>VIEW</span></button>
                    <button id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnArchive" style="display: none;"><span>ARCHIVE</span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="table-property">
                    <div>
    <table class="grid-view-style" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="color:#333333;height:20px;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr align="left" style="color:White;background-color:#1C5E55;font-weight:bold;">
            <th scope="col" style="width:60px;">Profile Pic</th><th scope="col" style="width:300px;">Full Name</th><th scope="col" style="width:120px;">National ID</th><th scope="col" style="width:70px;">Gender</th><th scope="col" style="width:120px;">Civil Status</th><th scope="col" style="width:120px;">Voter Status</th><th scope="col" style="width:120px;">Contact No</th><th scope="col" style="width:70px;">Action</th>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:#E3EAEB;">
            <td align="center" style="height:50px;width:50px;"><img src="../../App_LocalResources/Profile_BrgyCitizen/Philip_Formal_Attire.png" /></td><td>Jose Ang</td><td>111-1111-111</td><td>Male</td><td>Single</td><td>Yes</td><td>0999999999</td><td align="center" style="width:50px;">
                                    <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl02" title="View" src="../../Assets/css/barangay-official-page/images/icon-view.png" style="height:30px;width:30px;" />
                                    <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$ctl03" title="Archive" src="../../Assets/css/barangay-official-page/images/icon-archive.png" style="height:30px;width:30px;" />
                                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Inspect Element:
[image]

Comment: Try to remove ~ from the URL you saved in the database

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I did and it still the same output

Comment: Would you please send the output of img src here?
your src should be something like this "/App_LocalResources/Profile_BrgyCitizen/image.png" without any ~

Comment: What output? When I run the program?

Comment: Yes, the render result after you run the program

Comment: I edited the post and added the output

Comment: No I mean the HTML output, in your browser inspect the element of Img or use Ctrl+U and locate the <img src=

Comment: @WiloWisk can you right-click, inspect element on the broken image and share what the inspector shows you?

Comment: I edited the post for the the inspect element image icon and img src code @MahdiFarhani

Comment: Are you sure the Image URL in your database start with slash (/) ?

Comment: The image url in the db table is ```~/App_LocalResources/Profile_BrgyCitizen/image_name.png```

Comment: Are your sure about spelling of your folders and files ?

Comment: Yes I am, I double checked

Comment: @WiloWisk perhaps you can try replace the "~" in the StoredProcedure? `REPLACE(ProfilePic, '~', '')`

Comment: add another asp:ImageField outside the gridview control , after that find imageurl property , there you press ctrl + space it will ask to browse the image , after setting the image path , put the image path in the db also.

Comment: @Sund'er this worked! As it turns out, I tried to change the image path location. Rather than the ```App_LocalResources```, I made a separate independent folder ```~/Profile_Picture/``` for the images and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

what you have should work. Does the GV load, display other columns and data correctly??

And yes, since this is server side code, then the including the "~/ and your path name" is correct. Keep in mind that for markup, you can NOT use the "~", but you can and should use that format for server side code.

As a quick test?

Drag and drop the image from the solution explore into a blank clean area on the web page. It will and should spit out a image control for you.

so, for example, I have this:

[image]

So, lets double check the path name it will generate. But, remember, WHERE is your current page!!!!

My current page is Test5\fun.aspx

So, when I drag + drop in the image (just drag from project explore into the markup), you get this:

[image]

Note the path name it generated!!!

however, in my database, I do have this path name:

[image]

So, for a plain jane image image control?

You MUST remove the ~ in markup, (but keep the /).

But, for above, say grid view? Or any server side code?

then the "~" is fine.

So, lets send that data table to this grid:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = @"SELECT ID, Animal, ImagePath, PictureName FROM tblAnimals";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we now get this:

[image]

Also, NOTE VERY close, your size and width settings will not work.

You need to use this:

```
 <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" ControlStyle-Width="94px" />
```

So, use  ControlStyle-Width (and height if need be, but width usually does the job).

But, as noted, either your data is not being pulled, but if the other grid columns display, then you do have a path name error.